# Microsoft Access SQL Query Two Tables Many to One

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access

I have an art inventory table. It holds a contact id as a code39 barcode. On initialization, I need to be able to check this id against the ids contained in a contacts table. Each contact has its own id, and is designated a type. The initialization code needs to populate a list of artwork, but only by pieces that are owned by a contact of the types 'storage', 'show', and 'client'. I can VBA this, because I don't have a lot of coding time making Microsoft SQL statements, but I want to get the sql down. A contact can be referenced by an undefined number of pieces of art.

these statements do not work:\

```
strSQL = "SELECT [art_inventory_piece], [art_inventory_contact_id_code39]" & _
" FROM [Client Art Inventory] INNER JOIN [Client Contact]" & _
" ON [Client Art Inventory].art_inventory_contact_id_code39 = [Client Contact].contact_id_code39" & _
" WHERE [Client Contact].client_type = 'storage' or [Client Contact].client_type = 'show' or [Client Contact].client_type = 'client'"


strSQL = "SELECT [art_inventory_piece], [art_inventory_contact_id_code39]" & _
" FROM [Client Art Inventory]" & _
" WHERE [art_inventory_contact_id_code39]" & _
" in (select [contact_id_code39] from [Client Contact] where [contact_type]
  = 'storage' OR [contact_type] = 'show' OR [contact_type] = 'client')" & _
" ORDER BY [contact_id] ASC"
```

Comment: It is really difficult to tell what you are asking here. Can you explain in plain English what the goal of this code is? What do you mean by initialization in this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by "these statements do not work". Are you getting the wrong data, or no data, or are you getting an error, and if so what is it? Also, what database are you using? You talk about Microsoft SQL, but have also tagged it as mysql.

Comment: ODBC MySQL backend/Access Front End/Microsoft SQL statements construct recordset. pretty straight forward.

I went through a number of iterations(12) most errors are 'Too few parameters'. Syntax errors are pretty obvious. I am pretty sure my question is extremely basic.

Comment: If you reconstruct the queries in the query designer, what is the SQL-View code?

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. I haven't used the query builder at all, because I'm doing pass through, and it never seemed relevant. but I haven't used it, so maybe it is. I'm moving back to C++ at the end of this project(next week,) and it's not something I'll have anyway. I've gone 4000hrs without using it.

Answer (score 1):

I took TBridges advice and used the Query Builder, which I had never used. After a little mucking about it spit out this, with single double quotations. I put the rabbit ears back in and voila. The problem seems to be, I wasn't selecting from both tables, because I was thinking stepwise.

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Client Art Inventory].art_inventory_contact_id_code39, [Client Art Inventory].art_inventory_piece," & _
        " [Client Contact].contact_id_code39, [Client Contact].contact_type" & _
        " FROM [Client Art Inventory] INNER JOIN [Client Contact]" & _
        " ON [Client Art Inventory].art_inventory_contact_id_code39 = [Client Contact].contact_id_code39" & _
        " WHERE ((([Client Contact].contact_type)='storage' Or ([Client Contact].contact_type)='show' Or ([Client Contact].contact_type)='client'))"
```

[EDIT]

After looking at the problem a second time, it is clear that the select statement itself was not to blame. I only needed to see [Client Art Inventory].art_inventory_piece and adding the fields into the select statement doesn't even make sense. It seems that my formatting(bracketing) in the where statement was especially to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your issue is related to a misunderstanding: Microsoft SQL (aka TSQL) is used in MS SQL Server, but the SQL in Access is quite different.

Without seeing what you're actually doing with the strSQL (running it locally with DoCmd.RunSQL, or passing it to your MySQL instance) this is just a guess, but I would look at how you're delimiting your strings. MS Access uses doublequotes, proper SQL uses singlequotes.

Try

```
strSQL = "SELECT [art_inventory_piece], [art_inventory_contact_id_code39]" & _
" FROM [Client Art Inventory] INNER JOIN [Client Contact]" & _
" ON [Client Art Inventory].art_inventory_contact_id_code39 = [Client Contact].contact_id_code39" & _
" WHERE [Client Contact].client_type = ""storage"" or [Client Contact].client_type = ""show"" or [Client Contact].client_type = ""client"""
```

Comment: I had assumed at some point that the compiler was checking against Microsoft SQL because SQL and T-SQL were the same with inconsequential consequences. I know I have to do " ' "(no spaces) to insert parameters. 

I use Set rst_ctl = dbs_mac.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset). 

Single quotes for non coding text usually works, but I'll swap out and  give it a try.

Comment: neither statement works any better with double double quotations.

Comment: Access SQL works fine with single quotes too, it's just vba that requires double quotes (double quotes are just a little more conventional). That's not the cause of any errors